# How to handle multiple exceptions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a Python learner, trying to handle a few scenarios:

1. Reading a file.
2. Formatting Data.
3. Manipulating/Copying Data.
4. Writing a file.

So far, I have:

```
try:
   # Do all
except Exception as err1:
   print err1
   #File Reading error/ File Not Present

except Exception as err2:
   print err2
   # Data Format is incorrect
except Exception as err3:
   print err3
   # Copying Issue
except Exception as err4:
   print err4
   # Permission denied for writing
```

The idea of implementing in this fashion is to catch the exact error for all different scenarios. I can do it in all separate `try`/`except` blocks.

Is this possible?  And reasonable?

Comment: Yes what your doing is correct. For every exception type, just use the specific error you're going to catch. i.e. `except KeyError, ValueError`

Comment: I take that back, based on your scenario's, you are much better off creating multiple try catch blocks of code. i.e. `def check_file(file): try ... except your_ exceptions_here ... `

Comment: Basically the main idea of a try catch block is to do something, not do all, as multiple errors could be encountered along the way.

Comment: If what your trying to achieve is something like `try: read_file` then you could go with `except FileNotFound? ... except IsNotAFile? ...`.. but if your doing `try: read_file then crunch it` then yea, segregate them.

Comment: @Eduard Daduya : Multiple try/catch blocks is easy. I thought based on customized exceptions, i can handle single try with multiple exception blocks. Can it be done ?

Answer (score 12):

1. Your `try` blocks should be as minimal as possible, so

   ```
   try:
        # do all
   except Exception:
        pass
   ```

   is not something you want to do.
2. The code in your example won't work as you expect it to, because in every `except` block you are catching the most general exception type `Exception`. In fact, only the first `except` block will ever be executed.

What you want to be doing is having multiple `try/except` blocks, each one responsible for as few things as possible and catching the most specific exception.

For example:

```
try:
    # opening the file
except FileNotFoundException:
    print('File does not exist')
    exit()

try:
   # writing to file
except PermissionError:
   print('You do not have permission to write to this file')
   exit()
```

However, sometimes it is appropriate to catch different types of exceptions, in the same `except` block or in several blocks.

```
try:
    ssh.connect()
except (ConnectionRefused, TimeoutError):
    pass
```

or

```
try:
    ssh.connect()
except ConnectionRefused:
    pass
except TimeoutError:
    pass
```

Comment: So,do you suggest me to go with multiple try/catch blocks ?

Comment: Playing devil's advocate: didn't we make the leap from explicit error handling to exceptions that bubble up the stack *specifically* to get the ability to make larger `try` blocks and centralize error handling somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

As [DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace) stated,

> Your `try` blocks should be as minimal as possible.

If you want to achieve

```
try:
     # do all
except Exception:
     pass
```

Then you might as well do something like

```
def open_file(file):
    retval = False
    try:
        # opening the file succesful?
        retval = True
    except FileNotFoundException:
        print('File does not exist')
    except PermissionError:
        print('You have no permission.')
    return retval

def crunch_file(file):
    retval = False
    try:
        # conversion or whatever logical operation with your file?
        retval = True
    except ValueError:
        print('Probably wrong data type?')
    return retval

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if open_file(file1):
        open(file1)
    if open_file(file2) and crunch_file(file2):
        print('opened and crunched')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

Just say as example:

```
try:
    ...
except RuntimeError:
    print err1
except NameError:
    print err2

...
```

Just define the exact Error you want to intercept.