# try/except block catching multiple exceptions

Tags: python

I am trying to create a try except that catches 3 errors:

1. the first one if the user enters the name if the file which is not a txt file,
2. the second is if the file is empty then an error Is thrown and
3. the third is for if the file entered does not exist then an error is thrown as well.

I did try to do the first one where an error messages thrown if the file is not a txt file but I am also getting an error for that one saying 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

```
try:
   file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
   assert not file_name.contains(".txt")
except AssertionError:
   ("Error, must be a txt file")
file_fh = open(file_name)
counter = 0
avg = 0
for line in file_fh:
     if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): continue
     avg += float(line[20:-1].strip())
     counter = counter + 1
 print("Average spam confidence:", round(avg / counter, 4))
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: This error occurs because there is no `contains` method that can be invoked on strings in python. Please use `'.txt' in file_name` instead to check if `'.txt'` is present in `file_name`.

Comment: [How to handle multiple exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871016/how-to-handle-multiple-exceptions)

Comment: @thornejosh in this case it might be better to use `.endswith('.txt')`.

Comment: This seems like a questionable use of exceptions. A simple `if not file_name.lower().endswith(".txt")` should suffice. Exceptions should be used for "exceptional" cases. It is very unexceptional for a user to provide bad information.

Comment: I'll disagree slightly -- using an exception to represent "unexceptional" error conditions can be useful when you want to be able to quickly raise that condition to a higher level error handler in an outer scope without threading it back through each intervening scope (for example, if you want to be able to break a deeply nested loop, you can either set a flag that each loop has to check individually or you can raise from the inner scope and catch at the outer scope).  In this particular case, though, the exception pattern doesn't add any value.

Comment: Actually, while the `assert` on its own is kind of useless, there is some potential value here in terms of being able to put the entire block of code (with multiple error conditions that should each stop execution if encountered) under a single `try` -- maybe that's what OP was aiming for?  I'll put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to catch an exception anywhere in a large block of code, the entire thing needs to be within the same `try` block:

```
try:
    file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
    assert ".txt" in file_name, "Error, must be a txt file"
    file_fh = open(file_name)  # may raise FileNotFoundError
    counter = 0
    avg = 0
    for line in file_fh:
        if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): continue
        avg += float(line[20:-1].strip())
        counter = counter + 1
    assert counter, "File is empty!"
    print("Average spam confidence:", round(avg / counter, 4))
except (AssertionError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
    print(e)
```

In this example, the `assert` statements will obviously raise an `AssertionError` with the given message if the condition is not met.  The `open` call will raise `FileNotFoundError` if the file is missing, so to handle that case all you need to do is make sure your `except` block includes `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: for the line that contains except AssertionError, FileNotFoundError as e:
  print(e), I am getting an error saying python 3.8 doesn't support that syntax

Comment: Those should be two different lines.

Comment: oh woops -- also there need to be parens around there.  Fixed!

Comment: I tried it again and when I enter box.txt for some reason I am getting the error must be a txt file and when I enter a value that doesn't have .txt in it I am getting " [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'b' "

Comment: ah -- your original code had `assert not`... when you want the opposite.  Fixed that too.  Does the file called "b" exist?